# Can captured aliens escape?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I don't remember for sure, but I think it might have been mentioned in in-game dialogue that if I wait too long to interrogate captured aliens, then they might escape, because they're really dangerous after all.

Is this true? Will captured aliens eventually escape if you don't interrogate them within a certain numbers of days? If so, how long on average can you wait before a captured alien escapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is "flavour" for the story, not game mechanics. You can take as long as you like to interrogate aliens.